# jQuery: How to select all elements which have an attribute that is not equal to specific value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How could I select in jQuery all elements that have the `my_attr` attribute which is not equal to `my_value` ?

If `my_attr` is `a` and `my_value` is `"4"`, it should work like this:

```
<span>Hello</span>          => Not selected
<span a="5">Stack</span>    => Selected
<span b="4">Overflow</span> => Not selected
<span a="4">!!</span>       => Not selected
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get a "doesn't match", you'd use an [attribute not-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) with (the other part of the question) as [has-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/), like this:

```
$("span[a][a!='4']")
```

If you want it *to equal*, just take out the `!` for an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$("span[a][a='5']")
```

To use a variable, just concatenate, like this:

```
$("span[" + my_attr + "][" + my_attr + "!='" + my_value + "']")
```

Comment: Hi Nick! `$("span[a!='4']")` matches also all elements that does not have the `a` attribute. I would like to select only those which **does** have the `a` attribute, but it is not equals to `"4"`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/phMPw/

Comment: @Misha - not a problem, add a `has-attibute` selector like this: `span[a][a!='5']`, test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/phMPw/2/